# Login TFS programmatically using Windows Credentials

Tags: c#, authentication, tfs, credentials

I am currently trying to Login into my TFS without hardcoding or providing the Credentials via console or textbox.

Reason for this is that the Programm is going to be part of the nightly build process and should therefore use, if possible, the user that is currently logged in on the machine running the Programm.

I am absolutely clueless on how to solve this.
My current Approach as described above

```
tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("myTfsServer"), new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password));
```

where it should be more like.

```
tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("myTfsServer"), System.Windows.GetCurrentNetworkCredentials);
```

I havent found anything so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://__xxx__tfs:8080/tfs/__xxx__"));
        tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
```